# Perl looping program

Tags: perl

I am trying to write a program to accomplish the following:

> Use a loop structure and code a program that produces the following output (Take one parameter to let user specify how many lines need to be printed):
>
> ```
> A
> AA
> AAA
> AAAB
> AAABA
> AAABAA
> AAABAAA
> AAABAAAB
> ...
> ```

I can't get my program to run right. When I try to run it, nothing happens.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

$A = 3;
$B = 1;
$i = 1;
$output = "";
$j = 1;

while ($i <= $ARGV[0]) {
  while ($j <= $i) {
    if ($A == 0 && $B == 0) {
      $A = 3;
      $B = 1;
    }

    if ($A > 0) {
      $output.= "A";
      $A--;
    }
    else {
      $output.= "B";
      $B--;
    }

    &j++;
  }

  print($output  .  "/n");
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run it, I get this error:

> Can't modify non-lvalue subroutine call at  line ...

You used the wrong sigil.  Change:

```
&j++;
```

to:

```
$j++;
```

Also, you probably want `\n` instead of `/n`.

Answer (score 0):

This program does as you ask. It expects the number of list entries to be passed as a parameter on the command line, and defaults to eight if non is specified.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $max = shift // 8;

my $string;
my @strings;
push @strings, $string .= $_ & 3 ? 'A' : 'B' for 1 .. $max;

print "@strings\n";
```

**output**

```
A AA AAA AAAB AAABA AAABAA AAABAAA AAABAAAB
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change `&j++` to `$j++` and `print($output  .  "/n")` to `print($output  .  "\n")` then your program will work fine. However it does need some tidying, like this

```
$A      = 3;
$B      = 1;
$i      = 1;
$output = "";
$j      = 1;

while ($i <= $ARGV[0]) {
  while ($j <= $i) {

    if ($A == 0 && $B == 0) {
      $A = 3;
      $B = 1;
    }

    if ($A > 0) {
      $output .= "A";
      $A--;
    }
    else {
      $output .= "B";
      $B--;
    }

    $j++;
  }

  print($output . "\n");
  $i++;
}
```